# My question reached "10k views" but I haven't earned Famous Question badge yet

Tags: support, badges

I noticed yesterday that one of my questions ([Why is “iron” pronounced “EYE-URN” but not “EYE-RUN”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/264658/why-is-iron-pronounced-eye-urn-but-not-eye-run)) reached **10k views** but I haven't earned the "famous question" badge yet. I thought I would get the **[famous question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/badges/28/famous-question)** badge yesterday, but even after a day (or even more), I have not received the badge yet. Is it some kind of glitch or does my question need more views?

**UPDATE:** January 10 2021: I have now earned the badge ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not 10K yet, but the OP is very close.

The true number of views is visible when you hover the cursor over the 10K number, see the screenshot below, currently the correct number is 9,592.

[image]